# What would be a way to get all combinations of a NSString in Objective-C in a specific pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, nsstring, nsarray

I have a `NSString *strName = @"JonnySmith";`

What I want to do is get an `NSArray` of `NSStrings` with all possible combinations of a name, omitting certain characters. For example:

```
@"J";
@"Jo";
@"Jon";
```

but also combinations like:

```
@"JSmith";
@"JonSmith"
@"JonnSm";
@"JonSmt";
@"Smith";
@"th";
```

But they need to be in the order of the original name (the characters can't be out of order, just omitted). Basically traversing left to right in a loop, over and over again, until all possible combos are made.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Objective-C without make a mess?

Comment: @Sulthan - more like 768 surely?

Comment: @CRD Oh, I thought it's permutations, too. I see now it's only about character omission...

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if we can give you some pointers, everything here is abstract/pseudocode.

1. There are 2^n paths to follow, where *n* is the number of characters, as at each character you either add it or do not.
2. Taking your example after the first character you might produce `@""` and `@"J"`, then to each of these you either add the second character or not, giving: `@""`, `@"J"` (add nothing), `@"o"`, `"@Jo"`. Observe that if you have repeated characters anywhere in your input, in your sample you have two n's, this process may produce duplicates. You can deal with duplicates by using a *set* to collect your results.
3. How long is a character? Characters may consist of sequences of unicode code points (e.g.  - Belgium flag, if it prints in SO! *Letters* can be similarly composed), and you must not split these *composed sequences* while producing your strings. `NSString` helps you here as you can enumerate the composed sequences invoking a block for each one in order.

The above give you the pseudocode:

```
results <- empty set
for each composed character in input do block:
   add to results a copy of each of its members with the composed character appended
```

4. You cannot modify a collection at the same time you enumerate it. So "add to results" can be done by enumerating the set creating a new collection of strings to add, then adding them all at once after the enumeration:

   ```
   new items <- empty collection
   for every item in results
      add to new items (item appending composed character)
   results union new items
   ```
5. Optimising it slightly maybe: in (2) we had the empty string and in (4) we append to the empty string. Maybe you could not add the empty string to start and initialise *new items* to the *composed character*?
6. Hint: why did I write the non-specific *collection* in (4)?

Have fun. If you code something up and get stuck ask a *new* question, describe your algorithm, show what you've written, explain the issue etc. That will (a) avoid down/close votes and (b) help people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to consider every combination to be a mask of bits, where 1 means the character is there and 0 means the character is missing, for example:

`100010000` for `JonnySmith` will mean `JS`
   `000000001` for `JonnySmith` will mean `h`

It's simple to generate such masks because we can just iterate from `1` (or `000000001`) to `111111111`.
Then we only have to map that mask into characters.

Of course, some duplicates are generated because `1110...` and `1101...` will both be mapped to `Jon...`.

Sample implementation:

```
NSString *string = @"JonnySmith";
// split the string into characters (every character represented by a string)
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *characters = [NSMutableArray array];
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                        usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                            [characters addObject:substring];
                        }];

// let's iterate over all masks
// start with zero if you want empty string to be included
NSUInteger min = 1;
NSUInteger max = (1 << characters.count) - 1;

NSMutableString *buffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:characters.count];
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSUInteger mask = min; mask <= max; mask++) {
    [buffer setString:@""];

    // iterate over all bits in the generated mask, map it to string
    for (NSInteger charIndex = 0; charIndex < characters.count; charIndex++) {
        if ((mask & (1 << (characters.count - charIndex - 1))) != 0) {
            [buffer appendString:[characters objectAtIndex:charIndex]];
        }
    }
    // add the resulting string to Set, will handle duplicates
    [set addObject:[buffer copy]];
}
NSLog(@"Count: %@", @(set.count)); // 767
```

The size for `NSUInteger` will give us the maximum number of characters we can use using this method.

Comment: I like the idea behind the "bit mask" and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed the question is old but no answer is accepted. I think you can generate all permutations and then omit results which don't match your criteria (or tweak this code per your needs)

```
@interface NSString (Permute)
- (NSSet *)permutations;
@end

@implementation NSString (Permute)

- (NSSet *)permutations {
    if ([self length] <= 1) {
        return [NSSet setWithObject:self];
    }
    NSMutableSet *s = [NSMutableSet new];
    [s addObject:[self substringToIndex:1]];
    for (int i = 1; i < self.length; i++) {
        char c = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        s = [self words:s insertingLetterAtAllPositions:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",c]];
    }
    return [s copy];
}


- (NSMutableSet *)words:(NSSet *)words insertingLetterAtAllPositions:(NSString *)letter {
    NSMutableSet *collector = [NSMutableSet new];
    for (NSString *word in words) {
        [collector unionSet:[word allInsertionsOfLetterAtAllPositions:letter]];
    }
    return collector;
}

- (NSMutableSet *)allInsertionsOfLetterAtAllPositions:(NSString *)letter {
    NSMutableSet *collector = [NSMutableSet new];
    for (int i = 0; i < [self length] + 1; i++) {
        NSMutableString *mut = [self mutableCopy];
        [mut insertString:letter atIndex:i];
        [collector addObject:[mut copy]];
    }
    return collector;
}

@end

// usage
[@"abc" permutations];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it quite easily with a little recursion. It works like this:

- Check if the length is 1, then return an array of 2 elements, the empty string and the string.
- Call recursively with input string minus the first character and assign to sub-result.
- Duplicate the sub-result, adding the first character to each string.
- Return the result.

Remember to not call for empty string. If you want to omit the empty result string just remove the first element. Also, if you use the same letter several times, you will get some result strings several times. Those can be removed afterwards.

```
- (void)combinations:(NSString *)string result:(NSMutableArray *)result {
    if (string.length == 1) {
        [result addObjectsFromArray:@[ @"", string ]];
    } else {
        [self combinations:[string substringFromIndex:1] result:result];

        for (NSInteger i = result.count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            [result addObject:[[string substringToIndex:1] stringByAppendingString:result[i]]];
    }
}

// Call like this, for speed only one mutable array is allocated
NSString *test = @"0123456789";
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1 << test.length];
[self combinations:test result:result];
```